# Execute Dynamic query inside Select query in stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

I am trying to execute dynamic generated select query as a column value of `Select` statement. I tried using functions but that don't allow to execute dynamic query block.

Can anyone have way around to get me the desired solution?

```
create table #temp(column1 nvarchar(10), column2 nvarchar(10), column3 nvarchar(10));
insert into #temp exec fetch_some_data;

select 
columnX, 
columnY,
(select COALESCE('column3', null) from #temp a where coalesce('a.column1', null) = 'somevalue') as columnZ
from TableName
```

P.S.: This columns of #temp are not fixed, they are created dynamically from reading csv. Just for explanation they are added

Comment: Please, post sample data and expected results.

Comment: "This columns of #temp are not fixed" <-- could you elaborate? The names of the columns can be different but also the number of columns in #temp can vary? eg. if you fetch Address.csv then #temp(Name, Address, City) and if you fetch Person.csv then #temp(Fname, Lname, Age, Email)?  Or is it that the number of columns of #temp is always the same (i.e 3) an only the column names differ for each csv? It would be very helpful If you could provide a more detailed example,  for two different csv files and the corresponding sql that needs to be executed.

Comment: @lptr "This columns of #temp are not fixed"- This means the csv will be having different number of columns and name won't be fix.

Comment: thanks for the info. Could you provide more details on the query? (select COALESCE('column3', null) from #temp a where coalesce('a.column1', null) = 'somevalue') as columnZ ? you want to use all columns of #temp or only the columns at position 1 and 3? Just write the query when #temp has col1, col2, col3, col4, col5. A bit more of explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using functions but that don't allow to execute dynamic query
>   block.

You are on the right track. You can not use a normal tsql function (exec query limitation)  but you could use a scalar clr function.

How-to

Check the example of the clr function at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-ver15#example-of-a-clr-scalar-valued-function

for executing a dynamic statement, the sample code could be:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class T
{
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static object ExecDynamicSql(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn
            = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

compile it to a dll (either with visual studio or csc.exe)

then in ssms:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY DynamicSqlAssembly   
FROM 'C:\Users\..xyz...\Documents\Visual Studio xzy\Projects\xyz\xyz\bin\Debug\xyzname.dll'  --<-- path to dll here
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE; 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnExecSql(@query nvarchar(max)) 
RETURNS sql_variant
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME DynamicSqlAssembly.T.ExecDynamicSql;   
GO 


select dbo.FnExecSql('select getdate()');

select name, dbo.FnExecSql('select count(*) from ' + name) as tablecount
from sys.tables;
```

For completeness, you might want to add exception handling to the clr code and possibly return null when an exception occurs.It depends on your requirements.